# Interactive Brokers API connection without TWS

Tags: python, trading, interactive-brokers

Is it possible to connect to an IB account and trade, download market data, monitor positions etc. just with the API, without downloading TWS, in Python?

I worked with the TWS constantly opened and logged in, but didn't figure out of a way to connect without it

Comment: You can use the IB Gateway instead of TWS, but as far as I know, you can't just use Python.

Comment: maybe the web api https://www.interactivebrokers.com/api/doc.html